# Unable to set TextView background color in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, textview

I have a RecyclerView which contains TextView. The holder code is below:

```
private class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTitleTextView;
        public PhotoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView;
        }
        public void bindGalleryItem(GalleryItem item) {
            mTitleTextView.setText(item.toString());
            //--------------TEST CODE----------------
            mTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(2);
            mTitleTextView.invalidate();
            mTitleTextView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

Now, the line `mTitleTextView.setText()` works as expected but I also wanted to change background of the `TextView`. So, I tried calling the `setBackgroundColor()` method but even the call to invalidate and requestLayout don't set any background color.

Does anyone know a way to ensure setting of the background color? Is this the right place to set the color? Why is it not setting?

Also, I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: what is this value 2 that you are setting . It should be something like 0x0000FF

Comment: If you're actually using `2` for the color, that's going to be transparent. Use a proper hex value - `0xAARRGGBB` - or one of the methods in `Color` to generate a correct value.

Comment: @pulp_fiction Have you tried with `mTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d4d446"));`. Change your haxcode here.

Comment: I tried with other numbers too. It didn't work. In fact, I also tried with a random number generator and then also it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be 
`mTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOne));`

or to set the Text Color you can use the below

```
mTitleTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTwo));
```

Define your specific color in colors.xml

```
<color name="colorOne">#E60000</color>
<color name="colorTwo">#D3D3D3</color>
```

Color code are standards across different development activities. Android framework should understand the parameter value that you are planning to set to a view.
[Reference Link for Graphics color code](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

You can use softwares similar to [this](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) to find the color code

Comment: This worked! But, I don't understand why setting numbers randomly didn't work.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for pointing out. I was referring to a working code. For which colors.xml is having the referred value. I have updated my answer ! Hope I made my statement clear  :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove this :

```
mTitleTextView.invalidate();
mTitleTextView.requestLayout();
```

and ensure you are calling this method from right place i.e. nobody else is resetting textView's properties after it.

Comment: I tried without these methods also. It didn't work. Also, I am sure that no one else is setting the properties of this text view at any point after this.

Comment: can you post the code block which is calling this method

Answer (score 0):

Set your background color like this using color resources

```
//Like this you change your as your desire
mTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
```

Answer (score 0):

use like that :

> mTitleTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_red));